# TypeScript failing to infer parameter types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm initialising an object with a function property, and TypeScript is failing to infer the types of the parameters despite the tooltip indicating that the types for that property are known.

I'm trying to initialise the object like this:

```
const myObject: MyInterface<number> = {
   ...
   set: (value, args) => {}
}
```

The interface for this is defined like this:

```
export interface MyInterface<T> extends SomeOtherInterface<T> {
    set: (value: T, args: SetOptions) => void;
}
```

(I've changed the names of interfaces to make it easier to understand without context)

I get the error `Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type` and `Parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any' type` with this. If I hover over the `set` property in myObject, the tooltip correctly identifies the type definition as `(property) MyInterface<number>.set: (value: number, args: SetOptions) => void` so I'm struggling to see why TypeScript can't infer the types of the arguments?

I can explicilty define the argument types, however since they are being infered as `any` this would not be good - If the method signature of this changes, it won't trigger any compile time errors.

Does anyone know how to get TypeScript to correctly identify the types in this case?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAylEB5CICWB7AdgZxgXhgG8YdEAuGAVywGssMB3LGAX2DSxCgCcAzAIYBjWHAwBbKEhAALXgEkuvQSIA8AFQB8xdsCgAPCBh4gYnbv2GwAsmEUWVUDdoPcsAEzxjJ0uT3vKVs7EwDBhpBQwABQAbgIANlRQlOoANDACPADmOJQIyKiYuACUBNoxGGjuANzAukLYOKbiYEgARgBWUEIglLYBlmpYVOJtvNqERKFhZL3RcYlQ6Zk5pfjaROzsQA)

[image: Tooltip showing correct types for property are known]

[image: Tooltip showing implicit any]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on the TS playground (added link in your post) but everything is working as you would expect there. This might be a problem with your IDE, rather than TypeScript itself. If you can modify that playground snippet to reproduce this, we'll have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Hmm, yeah seems to be something a bit more complex causing the issue in my project... I'll try to reproduce in a sandbox